# In distributed computing, what are world size and rank?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytorch, distributed-computing

I've been reading through [some documentation](https://yangkky.github.io/2019/07/08/distributed-pytorch-tutorial.html) and [example code](https://github.com/narumiruna/pytorch-distributed-example/blob/master/toy/main.py) with the end goal of writing scripts for distributed computing (running PyTorch), but the concepts confuse me.

Let's assume that we have a single node with 4 GPUs, and we want to run our script on those 4 GPUs (i.e. one process per GPU). In such a scenario, what are the rank world size and rank? I often find the explanation for world size: *Total number of processes involved in the job*, so I assume that that is four in our example, but what about rank?

To explain it further, another example with multiple nodes and multiple GPUs could be useful, too.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

These concepts are related to parallel computing. It would be helpful to learn a little about parallel computing, e.g., [MPI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_Passing_Interface#Concepts).

You can think of `world` as a group containing all the processes for your distributed training. Usually, each GPU corresponds to one process. Processes in the `world` can communicate with each other, which is why you can train your model distributedly and still get the correct gradient update. So world size is the number of processes for your training, which is usually the number of GPUs you are using for distributed training.

`Rank` is the unique ID given to a process, so that other processes know how to identify a particular process. **Local rank is the a unique local ID for processes running in a single node**, this is where my view differs with @zihaozhihao.

Let's take a concrete example. Suppose we run our training in 2 servers (some articles also call them nodes) and each server/node has 4 GPUs. The world size is 4*2=8. The ranks for the processes will be `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]`. In each node, the local rank will be `[0, 1, 2, 3]`.

I have also written a post about MPI collectives and basic concepts. The link is [here](https://jdhao.github.io/2019/11/01/pytorch_distributed_training/).

Comment: I tried this `dist.init_process_group("gloo",rank=[0,1], world_size=2)` but got Error: Rank must be an integer. I don't understand

Comment: @mikey `init_process_group` is used by each subprocess in distributed training. So it only accepts a single rank, not a list of ranks.

Answer (score 12):

When I was learning `torch.distributed`, I was also confused by those terms. The followings are based on my own understanding and the API documents, please correct me if I'm wrong.

I think `group` should be understood correctly first. It can be thought as "group of processes" or "world", and one job is corresponding to one group usually. `world_size` is the number of processes in this `group`, which is also the number of processes participating in the job. `rank` is a unique id for each process in the `group`.

So in your example, `world_size` is 4 and `rank` for the processes is `[0,1,2,3]`.

Sometimes, we could also have `local_rank` argument, it means the GPU id inside one process. For example, `rank=1` and `local_rank=1`, it means the second GPU in the second process.

Comment: To further clarify, could you expand with another example? What would be the world size for two nodes with two GPUs each?

Comment: The world size is depend on how many processes are participating the job. So if you have two nodes, and one process per GPU. There are total four processes in this group, so the world size will be 4.

Comment: And rank will be [0, 1, 0, 1]?

Comment: @BramVanroy no, it will be 0,1,2,3. Rank is a unique id.