# What does local rank mean in distributed deep learning?

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, distributed-computing

https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/blob/master/examples/run_glue.py

I want to adapt this script to do text classification on my data. The computer for this task is one single machine with two graphic cards. So this involves kind of "distributed" training with the term `local_rank` in the script above, especially when `local_rank` equals 0 or -1 like in line 83.

After reading some materials from distributed computation I guess that `local_rank` is like an ID for a machine. And 0 may mean this machine is the "main" or "head" in the computation. But what is -1?

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/58271635/6064933

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Q: But what is -1?

Usually, this is used to disable the distributed setting. Indeed, as you can see [here](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/blob/155c782a2ccd103cf63ad48a2becd7c76a7d2115/examples/run_glue.py#L87):

```
train_sampler = RandomSampler(train_dataset) if args.local_rank == -1 else DistributedSampler(train_dataset)
```

and [here](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/blob/155c782a2ccd103cf63ad48a2becd7c76a7d2115/examples/run_glue.py#L116-L119):

```
if args.local_rank != -1:
    model = torch.nn.parallel.DistributedDataParallel(model, device_ids=[args.local_rank],
                                                      output_device=args.local_rank,
                                                      find_unused_parameters=True)
```

setting `local_rank` to `-1` has this effect.

Answer (score 1):

I want to add something more for the @Berriel's answer. Since you have two GPUs and not a distributed machine with a node structure, you do not need distributed methods like  **DistributedSampler**.  Hugginface use -1 to disable the distributed settings in training mechanisms.

Check out the following code from huggiface training_args.py script. As you can see if there is a distributed training mechanism  **self.local_rank** get changed.

```
def _setup_devices(self) -> "torch.device":

      
        logger.info("PyTorch: setting up devices")
        if self.no_cuda:
            device = torch.device("cpu")
            self._n_gpu = 0
        elif is_torch_tpu_available():
            device = xm.xla_device()
            self._n_gpu = 0
        elif is_sagemaker_distributed_available():
            import smdistributed.dataparallel.torch.distributed as dist

            dist.init_process_group()
            self.local_rank = dist.get_local_rank()
            device = torch.device("cuda", self.local_rank)
            self._n_gpu = 1
        elif self.local_rank == -1:
            # if n_gpu is > 1 we'll use nn.DataParallel.
            # If you only want to use a specific subset of GPUs use `CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=0`
            # Explicitly set CUDA to the first (index 0) CUDA device, otherwise `set_device` will
            # trigger an error that a device index is missing. Index 0 takes into account the
            # GPUs available in the environment, so `CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=1,2` with `cuda:0`
            # will use the first GPU in that env, i.e. GPU#1
            device = torch.device("cuda:0" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")
            # Sometimes the line in the postinit has not been run before we end up here, so just checking we're not at
            # the default value.
            self._n_gpu = torch.cuda.device_count()
```